# Install Ubuntu on Mac with non-EFI GPU

Tags: dual-boot, mac

I have a 2009 Mac Pro (4,1) with a non-EFI NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 GPU on which I'd like to install Ubuntu. I've created install media using the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), (tried USB and DVD) but when I attempt to enter the boot menu after restarting nothing is displayed on the monitor (the monitor goes into sleep mode). This presumably is due to not having an EFI GPU. Booting to OS X works fine though (I get a blank screen until OS X reaches the login screen).

One potential way around this is to select the disk to boot from from within OS X via the "startup disk" utility in system preferences but it only lists the OS X HDD, it doesn't seem to recognise the ubuntu disc as bootable.

Is there some way of getting the install disk recognised in "startup disk"? Or is it just impossible for me to install Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: AFAIK _all_ Intel Macs are EFI capable. EFI has nothing to do with the GPU whatsoever, and is a feature built into the BIOS. If you can't enter the boot menu, that isn't because your computer isn't EFI capable (it would have to be from pre-2000), it's a problem with the computer. Since this is a Mac issue really, I recommend asking it on either [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: My understanding is that the GPU has firmware which can be EFI compatible or BIOS compatible, mine is not EFI compatible. Not sure of the details though...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I don't think, though, that a GPU needs to work with EFI, as visuals and boot are separate, but I could be wrong.